# Oracle Scheduler stop job gives an exception when the job is not running

Tags: oracle, job-scheduling

I am getting an exception when I try to stop a scheduled job in oracle when this job is not running.

This is maybe normal but in my case I need to stop and disable the job before running some ddl operations.

If I check first the status of the job then there is no guarantee that it will not start just after the check. I don't know if it's clear.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
--Stop and Disable a job.
--Ignore exceptions about job not running, existing, or being unknown, since it's
--possible the job just finished.  This means there won't be an exception even if
--the job name is wrong.
declare
    v_not_running exception;
    v_does_not_exist exception;
    v_unknown_job exception;
    pragma exception_init(v_not_running, -27366);
    pragma exception_init(v_does_not_exist, -27476);
    pragma exception_init(v_unknown_job, -27475);
begin
    begin
        dbms_scheduler.stop_job('TEST_JOB');
    exception when v_not_running or v_does_not_exist or v_unknown_job then null;
    end;

    begin
        dbms_scheduler.disable('TEST_JOB');
    exception when v_not_running or v_does_not_exist or v_unknown_job then null;
    end;
end;
/
```